Evaluate the flexi deposits early redemption risk using swaption pricing method
When I use swaption pricing method to evaluate the flexi-deposits early redemption customer behavioural option, I should calculate the spread as a input to the quantlib swaption object. Should I take the breakage cost into consideration by deducting base rate and break cost from contractual interest rate?
